# SAS URL String-to-Sign includes extra newline characters (Azure)

Tags: typescript, authentication, sdk, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

We are creating a User-Delegation-based SAS URL to an Azure storage blob in our Typescript application, but our string-to-sign has extra newline (and ".") characters and we can't figure out why. Below is our code to create the token. What are we doing wrong? We cannot manually configure the string-to-sign, it must be done properly and programmatically.

CODE:
`

```
   public async getStorageCredentials(
        tenant: string, subproject: string,
        bucket: string,readonly: boolean,partition: string): Promise<IAccessTokenModel> {
        const endpoint = await AzureDataEcosystemServices.getStorageEndpoint(partition);
        const now = new Date();
        const expiration = this.addMinutes(now, SasExpirationInMinutes);
        const sasToken = await this.generateSASToken(endpoint, bucket, expiration, readonly);
        const result = {
            access_token: sasToken,
            expires_in: 3599,
            token_type: 'SasUrl',
        };
        return result;
    }

    private async generateSASToken(
        endpoint: string,
        containerName: string,
        expiration: Date,
        readOnly: boolean): Promise<string> {

        const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
            endpoint,
            this.defaultAzureCredential
        );

        const accountName = blobServiceClient.accountName;

        const userDelegationKey = await this.getDelegationKey(blobServiceClient);

        const permissions = new ContainerSASPermissions();
        permissions.list = true;
        permissions.write = !readOnly;
        permissions.create = !readOnly;
        permissions.delete = !readOnly;
        permissions.read = true;

        const containerSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
            containerName,
            permissions,
            protocol: SASProtocol.Https,
            expiresOn: expiration
        }, userDelegationKey, // UserDelegationKey
            accountName);
        return `${endpoint}${containerName}?${containerSAS.toString()}`;
    }

    private async getDelegationKey(blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient): Promise<UserDelegationKey> {
        const key = blobServiceClient.accountName;
        const now = new Date();
        const cache = this.delegationKeyMap.get(key);
        if (cache && cache.expiration > now) {
            return cache.key;
        }

        const expiresOn = this.addMinutes(now, UserDelegationKeyValidityInMinutes);

        // Getting a key that is valid from ExpirationLeadInMinutes ago, in order to handle clock differences
        const response = await blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(
            this.addMinutes(now, -ExpirationLeadInMinutes),
            expiresOn);

        // Expiring the key ExpirationLeadInMinutes before it stops being valid in order to handle clock differences
        const keyExpiration = this.addMinutes(expiresOn, -ExpirationLeadInMinutes);
        this.delegationKeyMap.set(key, { key: response, expiration: keyExpiration });

        return response;
    }
```

We want our string-to-sign to look like this:

`rcwdl 2022-11-24T02:47:27Z /blob/<storage-account-name>/<container> 103adf72-21be-44fe-b948-c068ab79eb6 72f98bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47 2022-10-22T03:17:01Z 2022-11-24T02:47:27Z b 2021-06-08 2021-06-08 c`

But unfortunately it looks like this:

`rcwdl..2022-11-24T02:47:27Z./blob/<storage-account-name>/<container>.fbbcff7e-3f21-4eb4-adc4-80245934e61.33e0191-4d64-4f8c-a055-5bdaffd5e33d.2022-11-21T14:33:27Z.2022-11-24T02:47:27Z.b.2020-10-02.....https.2020-10-02.c......`
`

We tried to leverage typescript code and the [SDK for Azure Blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/90fc8ae26192bf8296e372afbfb62a4b2b3a1d8e/sdk/storage/storage-blob/src/BlobServiceClient.ts) to create a SAS URL and it is failing. Because the string to sign is wrong, the final error we see is `AuthenticationErrorDetail: Signature did not match. String to sign used was rcwdl`

Answer (score 0):

***I tried in my environment and got below results:***

**Code:**

```
const {DefaultAzureCredential} = require('@azure/identity');
const { BlobServiceClient,ContainerSASPermissions,
generateBlobSASQueryParameters,
SASProtocol,ContainerClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

  
async  function  createContainerSas() {
const  accountName = "venkat123";
const  containerName="test";
const  blobname="sample.txt";
const  blobServiceClient = new  BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
 new  DefaultAzureCredential()
);

const  userDelegationKey = await  blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(new  Date(), new  Date(new  Date().valueOf() + 10 * 60 * 1000));

const  permissions = new  ContainerSASPermissions();
permissions.list = true;
permissions.write = true;
permissions.create = true;
permissions.delete = true;
permissions.read = true;

const  sasOptions = {
blobname,
containerName,
permissions,
protocol:  SASProtocol.Https,
startsOn:  new  Date(),
expiresOn:  new  Date(new  Date().valueOf() + 10 * 60 * 1000)
};

const  sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters( 
sasOptions,
userDelegationKey,
accountName
).toString();
const  sasUrl = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobname}?${sasToken}`;
console.log(`\nBlobUrl = ${sasUrl}\n`);
}

createContainerSas();
```

**Console:**
I tried with blob level with **`sas-token`** and it successfully executed.

[image]

**SAS-token:**

```
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.txt?sv=2021-10-04&spr=https&st=2022-11-29T12%3A08%3A56Z&se=2022-11-29T12%3A18%3A56Z&skoid=6e19aa9e-1e69-4a85-85f4-b00099a8da5c&sktid=72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47&skt=2022-11-29T12%3A08%3A53Z&ske=2022-11-29T12%3A18%3A53Z&sks=b&skv=2021-10-04&sr=c&sp=rcwdl&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Browser:**

*I checked the url with browser it worked.*

[image]